# React AuthContext : on page reload data is lost

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, local-storage, authorization

i am using AuthContext and AuthProvider in React.js.

After login, the page is redirected to the dashboard page where i am showing the username. As we can see in below picture. The issue i am facing is If i refresh the page 'username' disappear.

[image]

Here is the code:

**login.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "../auth/AuthProvider";

export default function Login() {

  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const auth = useAuth();
  const handleSubmitEvent = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (input.username !== "" && input.password !== "") {
      auth.loginAction(input);
      return;
    }
    alert("pleae provide a valid input");
  }

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setInput((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  }

  return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmitEvent}>
<div className='container mt-5'> 
<div className='row'>

<div className='col-12 mb-2'> 
<div> Username:</div>
<div>    
  <input
    className='form-control'
    type="text"
    name='username'
    id='username'
    onChange={handleInput}
    /></div>
</div>

<div className='col-12 mb-2'> 
<div>Password:</div>
<div>
<input
    className='form-control'
    type="password"
    id="password"
    name="password"
    onChange={handleInput}
    />
</div>

</div>
<div className='col-12 mb-2'> 
    <button 
    className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>

  )
}
```

**AuthProvider.js**

```
import { useContext, createContext, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";


const AuthContext = createContext();
const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  const [token, setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem("site") || "");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const loginAction = async (data) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/auth/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      })

      const res = await response.json();
        console.log(res)

    if (res) {
      setUser(res);
      setToken(res.token);
      localStorage.setItem("site", res.token);
      navigate("/dashboard");
      return;
    }  

    throw new Error(res.message);
      
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }


  const logOut = () => {
    setUser(null);
    setToken("");
    localStorage.removeItem("site");
    navigate("/login");
  }


  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ token, user, loginAction, logOut }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )

}

export default AuthProvider;

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useAuth } from "../auth/AuthProvider";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>
        <h1>Hi, {auth.user?.username} </h1>
        <button onClick={() => auth.logOut()} className="btn-submit">
          logout
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../auth/AuthProvider";

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const { token } = useAuth();
  if (!token) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />
  }
  return <Outlet />
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Comment: You never save user in the localStorage

Comment: username and token showing in Local storage.
in AuthProvider.js
      setToken(res.token);
      localStorage.setItem("site", res.token);